# Replace path and quotes with new url in file

Tags: php, string, file

I have a text file with the following data:

```
"K:\data\etrdtCfhbr6MUkAAFuVw.jpg"
"K:\data\rgtdrCfhbr6OUYAE5lNR.jpg"
"K:\data\Cfhbr6VVIrdtdAAmRPr.jpg"
"K:\data\Cffh-EyWsersetsAQ8eIz.jpg"
```

I want to replace the quotes and part of the path to get an output like this:

```
http://myweb.com/dat/etrdtCfhbr6MUkAAFuVw.jpg
http://myweb.com/dat/rgtdrCfhbr6OUYAE5lNR.jpg
http://myweb.com/dat/Cfhbr6VVIrdtdAAmRPr.jpg
http://myweb.com/dat/Cffh-EyWsersetsAQ8eIz.jpg
```

Right now I have some (pseudo)code where I don't know how to get it working correctly:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt'); //Load the file contents 
$newcontent = preg_replace('.....', $filecontents); //Use a regex to replace the stuff as I want
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $newcontent);
```

I highlighted the code where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: [2] @Rizier123 What code have you tried to use?

Comment: i bet there is a single function to do this in the manual

Comment: $filecontents = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt'); //Load the file contents
    $newcontent = preg_replace('.....', $filecontents); //Use a regular expression to alter the file contents. The replacement (.${4}) adds the . and the file extension back into the line.
    file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $newcontent);

Comment: i don't know used preg_replace

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: you dont even need a regular expression `str_replace()` will work just fine

Comment: This seams to be a one time job. If you don't know how preg_replace works then loop through the lines and use str_replace().

Comment: @vallez I've just saw a few of your questions and when you debug a code always, always turn on error reporting: `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of each file and then google those if you get any. And or look up the function in the manual about which you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your file as a string with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Then you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace each path as you want. And with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) you simply save the file back.

The regex `/\".*\\\\(.*?)\"/m` simply means:

- `\".*\\\\` match a double quote(`\"`) and then everything(`.*`) until the last backslash(`\\\\`)
- `(.*?)\"` match everything(`(.*?)`) until a double quote(`\"`)
- `m` modifier m simply means to use the regex for each line

Code

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents("test.txt");
    $file = preg_replace("/\".*\\\\(.*?)\"/m",  "http://myweb.com/dat/$1", $file);
    file_put_contents("test.txt", $file);

?>
```

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is of no benefit because there is no `^` or `$` in the pattern.  `m` does not mean "use the regex for each line".